# Как узнать локальный ip адрес устройства в Wi-Fi?

Tags: ip, android, wifi, java

Как узнать ip адрес устройства в локальной сети, при условии что устройство выступает точкой доступа?

Comment: Используя API java, android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573196/how-to-get-the-ip-of-the-wifi-hotspot-in-android

Вот аналогичный вопрос. Ответ есть.

Comment: @smackmychi, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score -2):

В Ubunte команда: `ifconfig`

В Windows: `ipconfig`

Comment: Метки `android` и  `java` как бы намекают.

Comment: Надо уметь четко ставить вопрос! А не намекать и не заставлять людей догадываться

Comment: Надо уметь читать весь вопрос, а не только заголовок!

Comment: У некоторых нет времени читать то, что написано мелким шрифтом и "под звёздочками".
Вопрос должен быть чётко сформулирован. И не быть размытым по всей области применения.